# What does "check" mean in "check your privilege"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

The phrase "check your privilege" is currently enjoying some popularity on the Internet.  It seems that "check" could have several meanings:

- holding back so as to avoid applying unwanted force: "The batter checked her swing."
- examine closely: "This item has been checked for defects."
- give to one's host for safekeeping: "All firearms must be stowed in checked baggage."

Which meaning best applies in this phrase?  It's not entirely clear if the intent is to get people to halt the oppressive use of unearned authority (the "holding back" or "safekeeping" meanings) or to get people to look more carefully at it (the "examine" meaning).

Comment: It could have either of the first two meanings, depending on the context. I'd need to see the text to be able to comment further.

Comment: "Checked" as in "checked baggage" is a contraction of "checked-in", anyway. You _check in_ baggage to a flight, in much the same way you _check in_ computer program code to a version control system.

Comment: I would suggest that #3 is not the intended meaning: "You have an unearned, favorable perspective/position inherent to what (not who) you are." That's not something you can forfeit. Meanings #1 or #2 (or both) are possible in different contexts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here it is being discussed on [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/society/2013/jun/05/check-your-privilege-means)...

> roughly speaking, ["check your privilege"] is a way of telling a person who is making a political point that they should remember they are speaking from a privileged position, because they are, for example, white, male, heterosexual, able-bodied or wealthy.

Of OP's suggested meanings for ***check***, the best one is ***examine closely***.The person being addressed is being told/reminded that he should consider carefully whether the opinions he's expressing might perhaps owe more to his privileged perspective than to objective reasoning. Obviously in practice the strong implication is that the speaker invariably thinks it *does*.

---

As @Janus comments below, it's perfectly possible to interpret the usage as a combination of OP's #1 and #3 *(leave your privileged perspective outside when you enter this discussion)*. It should normally be obvious from context which exact sense the speaker intends (is he giving advice *before* you express any opinion at all, or *after* you said something ascribable to privileged circumstances?).

The difference in meaning between the two is relatively small, and it's quite possible that different speakers (or the same speakers at different times) may have either "nuance" in mind.

Comment: A combination of senses 1 and 3 is also possible: “check your privilege (at the door before participating in this discussion)” is how I've always understood it in the contexts I've seen it. I'd say the fact that the verb is so ambiguous and hard to pin down exactly has caused people to understand it in different ways and consequently also use the expression in different ways matching the different senses of the verb.

Comment: It isn't a polite reminder; in fact, it is an aggressive admonishment but as of late, I have heard it used in jest

Comment: @Janus: Point taken. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: The problem with anything like that is it just ends up meaning, "Your opinion is worthless because either you have money, or you were born into a position some other people feel is automatically privileged." It's a standard ad hominem.

Comment: @Third News: May I remind you that "reminders" aren't necessarily "polite". This one obviously *is*, but my *"person being addressed is being told/reminded"* above carried no such implication. The opposite, in fact, since my next sentence strongly implies the admonition is invariably made in a spirit of negative criticism.

Comment: I was trying to express that the statement is used as a replacement for 'STFU', and the Guardian definition gives the impression it is about conversing

Comment: @Third News: Well, it *is* The Guardian, after all. A significant proportion of whose readership is retired civil servants and others who have index-linked pensions paid for by the state. Since they mostly speak from a "privileged position", it's hardly surprising that their overall position re the usage would be somewhat disparaging. Just like everyone else, Guardian columnists and readers typically take it for granted that they can evaluate the hardship of others objectively, even though it's a million miles from their own personal experience.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'll ask you the same question I asked Third News: given that "check your privilege" is an imperative phrase, what action is the speaker mandating?  Is it mandating self-examination, or is it mandating self-restraint?

Comment: @sigil: I'm not sure where you get that "mandating self-restraint" interpretation from. The two possibilities are either (a) "mandating self-examination" (per my first two paragraphs in the answer), and (b) "mandating **objectivity**" (as per Janus's comment and my third paragraph). Any element of "self-restraint" would be an extremely "indirect" inference, and I see no implications of *one should **be quiet about** one's privilege.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: given your 3rd paragraph, "mandating objectivity" seems to equal "mandating restraint", i.e., do not allow your privilege to interfere with your objectivity. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @sigil: Yes. Is it possible you don't understand the usage *"Check your hat and coat at reception"*? I don't see what is so hard to grasp about this, and I *still* don't understand why you keep introducing the concept of "restraint". That is one possible sense of "check", but it has nothing to do with the expression under consideration here.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone's missing the simple answer:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=check

> 1. to put someone in their place
> 2. to realize your current position in any of many situations
> 3. paper money you write
>
> *best check yo self, before you reck yourelf*

In particular, the cited example is probably the phrase that most popularized this usage of the word *check*:

http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/icecube/checkyoself.html

Comment: That may be the meaning (something between #1 and #2), but it's not obvious. "Check yourself" here _apparently_ means to "Stop and consider your attitude, position, and assumptions before proceeding, and possibly making an ass of yourself."

Comment: I looked at the Ice Cube track when formulating the question.  I think if we use "Check Yo Self" as a guide to the definition, it would be the "examine closely" definition because the lyrics include "run a check", which means querying a database.  But I wasn't sure, because the tone of the lyrics is also fairly combative, which suggests a meaning closer to the "restrain" definition.

Answer (score -1):

This phrase has been in use among information technologists for decades, where user privs are registered and enforced by the information system involved.

It was inevitable that the usage of the phrase would sooner or later spill into the general public. For the past few decades, it has even been used as an organizational and process management idiom.

The recent exposure of this phrase to lay usage would mean its meaning is still fluid, such that it is begging everyone including yourself to use it as you see fit, but in a reasonable manner that is idiomatic or analogous to its IT or management usage.

To contribute to the solidification of its meaning, I recommend the following usage ...

- before you offend the organizational inertia, check your pay grade in comparison to the procedures or opinions you wish to displace.
- to avoid getting frustrated and encountering insurmountable road blocks, check your authoritativeness in the subject and fields concerned
- before getting frustrated by organizational inertia, check your cognizance by the people and systems with whom you wish to rub shoulders.
- check the charter and bylaws of an organization (like a country club or gated community) whether your standing would allow you to pursue your intent.
- check quality specs, SOPs (std operating procs), ISO 9000 etc, legal constraints of your organization if you are among those allowed to pursue your intent.
- check your caste/social/class/nerd/popularity status (like before attempting to date someone),

It can be an advice or admonishment given, in sarcasm, condescension, or well-meaning concern. It is *consideration of standing compared to inertia* to be made before taking on an endeavour.

#### Appendix

One of the corollaries of checking your privileges, is the priority with which you are perceived by others.

In computing (as well as management) a low priority entity would not have its tasks completely blocked but it would receive lesser attention and allowed less resources to complete its task. Frequently, a low privilege entity would also correlate to low priority.

Therefore, when you encounter situations where your issues and problems are resolved more slowly than others, it is also time to check your privileges.

The antithetical resolutions to use against low privileges and priorities are elevation, escalation, and expediting. A process planner would take steps to "bump up" the priorities of a product that is perceived to be moving too slowly by either elevating its product status both in both the information systems as well as among the human organisational perception.

The more obvious solution to your low standing is to canvass the support of a high standing member to be the proxy-front of your tasks.

Therefore, on discovering your privileged standing in a country club to be too low, and you wish to hold your wedding there next month, you should either request for a temporary elevation in status, a one time escalation, or look for a member of high privileges to move the mountains for you.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the phrase's usage among the IT community?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_(computing)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Comment: This is utterly, completely wrong, and isn't at all the etymology of this word. I have never, ever heard an IT person use the phrase "check your privilege". [This google trends graph](https://www.google.com.au/trends/explore#q=%22check%20your%20privilege%22) shows it exploded quite recently, but had no usage before 2012. Not the "decades" you suggested.

Comment: +Lego, for the last 20 years, I've had to deal with uttering or hearing this phrase a few times a week. It is impossible to escape this phrase for IT professionals. We originated this phrase. The very function of privs was invented by IT to segregate what users can or cannot do. Are you saying that a field obsessed with assigning privs, would not say, "Let's check the privs of this process", "or user". "How was this accident allowed to happen. Let's check if we have assigned this user to high privs."

Comment: Privs obsession and assignment is the bedrock of anger and annoyance against IT. +Lego, have you never had the priv to work in an organization with an IT dept before?

Comment: This is completely wrong, sorry. Just because computer systems use the term "privileges" to describe access control, does not mean that "check your privilege" originated in IT. The term "privilege" has a _completely_ different meaning here, as does the "check". So the only thing they have in common is "the"; woop woop

Comment: We have been using the phrase a few times a week, for the last twenty years over multiple companies I had worked for - "Please check his/her privs", "check the your privs", "check your process privs". And then the same phrase was used when dealing with human issues by us in sarcasm or in allegory, naturally. We would tell a colleague "Why don't you check your privs first?" if he/she wanted to do something out of the blue. You can't invalidate all that usage that has been going on the last 20 years by a magic wand of opinion.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, the main difference here is that in my original post, "privilege" is being used as an uncountable noun.  Your IT usage examples all use it as a countable, because in the IT world a "privilege" is a discrete object--a value in a permissions table.  Do you have any examples of the actual phrase "check your privilege", with "privilege" in the uncountable sense, in historical use in an IT setting?